# Update an ObservableCollection with a background worker in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

Ok, I recently implemented a background worker to perform saving and loading of data.

However, getting this to work on a save command has proved difficult.

Basically, my save command generates an event, that notifies a collection view model, that an Item has been added and that the item should be added to its own ObservableCollection.

At this point, I get the usual exception saying I can NOT update an ICollection on a different thread. I have tried creating a new list type that calls `Dispatcher.Invoke`, however this still generates the same exception.

I was wondering whether anyone else has any suggestions on how best to tackle this?

So currently I have a class that Inherits from ObservableCollection:

```
public class ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection(List<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            if (index > this.Count)
                return;
            LockCookie c = rwLock.UpgradeToWriterLock(-1);
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
            rwLock.DowngradeFromWriterLock(ref c);
        }
        else
        {
            object[] obj = new object[] { index, item };
            dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Send, 
                (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { InsertItemImpl(obj); }, 
                obj);
        }
    }
```

I then have a view model class that has a background worker which carries out the save.

Once the save is complete, an event is fired to another view model to update its list.

```
    protected override void OnObjectAddedToRepository(object sender, ObjectEventArgs<cdAdministrators> e)
    {
        Dispatcher x = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        var viewModel = new AdministratorViewModel(e.EventObject, DataAccess);
        viewModel.RecentlyAdded = true;
        viewModel.ItemSelected += this.OnItemSelected;
        this.AllViewModels.Add(viewModel);
        RecentlyAddedViewModel = viewModel;

        OnPropertyChanged(null);
    }
```

Both lists are created by a separate background worker thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where you've got code which adds the item to the observable collection (presumably in the view model), wrap that `Add` call in a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call.

Admittedly that means the view model needs to know about the dispatcher, which then becomes awkward to test... fortunately it's not too hard to introduce your own `IDispatcher` interface and use dependency injection in the normal way.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your reply, I Already have a collection object, which Inherits from ObserveableCollection on InsertItem this does Dispatcher.CheckAccess if false then does Dispather.BeginInvoke, however this is still not working??

Comment: @jpgooner: Are you sure that code is actually being used? Can you come up with a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have added more detail above, let me know if you need anymore, I am still new to stackoverflow

Comment: figured it out thanks to your response, because the background thread was creating some on the collections check access was returning true, when inactual fact i needed to compare to the UI thread!  Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
public class ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext;

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection()
    {
        SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // current synchronization context will be null if we're not in UI Thread
        if (SynchronizationContext == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This collection must be instantiated from UI Thread, if not, you have to pass SynchronizationContext to con                                structor.");
    }

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection(SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
    {
        if (synchronizationContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("synchronizationContext");

        this.SynchronizationContext = synchronizationContext;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.ClearItems()), null);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.InsertItem(index, item)), null);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.RemoveItem(index)), null);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.SetItem(index, item)), null);
    }

    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex)), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a [blog post](http://michlg.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/dispatchingobservablecollection-thread-save-observablecollection/) that uses the Dispatcher to manage all of the ObeservableCollection's methods.  Here is a snip-it of the code, see the [post](http://michlg.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/dispatchingobservablecollection-thread-save-observablecollection/) for the entire class.

```
public class DispatchingObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor of the ObservableCollection
    /// </summary>
    public DispatchingObservableCollection()
    {
        //Assign the current Dispatcher (owner of the collection)
        _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    private readonly Dispatcher _currentDispatcher;

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes this action in the right thread
    /// </summary>
    ///<param name="action">The action which should be executed</param>
    private void DoDispatchedAction(Action action)
    {
        if (_currentDispatcher.CheckAccess())
            action();
        else
            _currentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all items
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        DoDispatchedAction(() => base.ClearItems());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a item at the specified index
    /// </summary>
    ///<param name="index">The index where the item should be inserted</param>
    ///<param name="item">The item which should be inserted</param>
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        DoDispatchedAction(() => base.InsertItem(index, item));
    }
```

Comment: Good example! Just a small correction: protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item) { DoDispatchedAction(() => BaseInsertItem(index, item)); } is in fact protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item) { DoDispatchedAction(() => base.InsertItem(index, item)); }

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure why I explicitly created one method and used an anonymous method for the second example.  I've cleaned them up.